# Struggling to understand the associative property of multiplication of matrices.

Tags: matrices

Let me start of the question by quoting a excerpt about the associative property of multiplication "The associative property of multiplication states that the way in which the numbers are grouped in a multiplication problem does not affect or change the product of those numbers."
i.e., A(BC)=(AB)C which makes perfect sense and also works for matrices but where I get a bit confused is that A(BC)=(AB)C≠B(CA) is true for matrices but for real numbers it is A(BC)=(AB)C=B(CA)
which leads me to believe that maybe I don't properly understand Associative and commutative property of multiplication to begin with. Thoughts? (And yes I know that the commutative law of multiplication does not hold for matrices)
Side note:  I know my question structuring is bit crass but please bear with me as English is not my first language and I am only a high school student.

Comment: You have $A(AB)$ twice. Do you really mean that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say A(BC)=A(AB)=B(CA)?

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake fixed now.

Comment: You say you know matrix multiplication need not commute. Commutativity is exactly what you need along with associativity to prove $A(BC)=(AB)C=B(CA)$

Comment: When you say that $A(BC)=B(CA)$ for real numbers, while that is true that is *not* a direct result of associativity.  Associativity does not say one way or another whether $A(BC)$ should or should not equal $B(CA)$.  In order to prove that $A(BC)$ is equal to $B(CA)$ you need *both* associativity *and* commutativity to hold.  There is no contradiction here.

Comment: $A(BC)\color{red}{=}A(CB) \color{blue}{=} (AC)B\color{red}{=}B(AC)\color{red}{=}B(CA)$ where the red equals signs are due to commutativity and the blue equals sign is due to associativity.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity is that $ABC=(AB)C=A(BC)$  holds for all matrices $A,B,C$ of appropriate dimensions. Multiplication is associative for matrices.

Commutativity is that $AB=BA$ for all matrices $A,B$ of appropriate dimensions. Commutativity does not hold in general for matrices. If two matrices $A,B$ have the same eigenvectors, then $A$ and $B$ commute, but this is not true in general. For instance, if we pick two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then we have that $u^Tv\in\mathbb{R}$ but $vu^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.